# Create cron job for every five minutes?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to Magento 1.9. I have my own custom API which read last modified Product stock and do some updates. **I need to make this API run every five minutes** . 
Please help.

Comment: You know how to setup a cronjob ? https://blog.amasty.com/configure-magento-cron-job/

Comment: @Klettseb. Thank you for your comment. I checked the link, it is good. but I need to do the cron programmatically as a module. I need a full detailed description.